# Crypto++ giving a compiler error in algparam.h

Tags: c++, crypto++

I have the following lines in a rather large file:

```
#include <sha.h>
#include <hex.h>
```

Which, when compiled, throws this compiler error:

```
1>d:\work\app\tools\cryptopp\algparam.h(322): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'buffer'
1>          d:\work\app\tools\cryptopp\algparam.h(321) : while compiling class template member function 'void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>::MoveInto(void *) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=bool
1>          ]
1>          d:\work\app\tools\cryptopp\algparam.h(329) : see reference to class template instantiation 'CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=bool
1>          ]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm forgetting something, but I'm not sure what. If I don't include hex.h, I don't have any problems and I get a SHA256 hash just fine, but when I do include hex.h, the error pops up.

**Edit**

In case anyone wonders, from algparam.h of Crypto++ toolkit:

```
void MoveInto(void *buffer) const //<=== line 320
{
    AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>* p = new(buffer)
    AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>(*this);
}

CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS AlgorithmParametersTemplate<bool>; // <== line 329
```

**Edit**: Removed unrelated code

Comment: Is this the entire text of the error? Are there other errors? Is there any link between the code of `InitEngine` you quote, and this error? The error text does not reference it, or anything inside it. Does the error still happen when you comment `InitEngine` out?

Comment: Nope, none of the code references this `MoveInto` function. However, hex.h seems to include basecode.h, which includes algparam.h. It seems that whenever algparam.h gets included, it fails.

Comment: And yes, it still happens if I comment the code in `InitEngine` out.

Comment: If `InitEngine` is not relevant, please remove it from the question. Now if you comment out everything except the two includes, does it fail? What if you only leave `hex.h`?

Comment: If I only include `hex.h`, it fails with the same error.

Comment: So the problem is that you cannot use hex.h. Apparently it uses *placement new* syntax and some (old, broken) Microsoft compilers balk at it, unless you also `#include <new>`. Try adding this to your file.

Comment: I have now added this, and I'm still seeing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Angelo. I've never seen this error before, but it was added to the Crypto++ wiki at  [NameValuePairs](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/NameValuePairs#Compile_Error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem by temporarily undefining `new`, which was defined as a macro to some extra debugging code.

```
#pragma push_macro("new")
#undef new
/* #includes for Crypto++ go here */
#pragma pop_macro("new")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're including Crypto++ in a Visual Studio project with MFC support, this error might be caused by this line:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif
```

Make sure to remove it or comment it out.

Comment: @AngeloGeels: That line is not in the MFC header. It's added into `.cpp` files generated by the MFC wizard.

Comment: Ah, I see - still, it's probably not a good idea to comment it out if my answer above fixes the issue as well.

Comment: @AngeloGeels: `DEBUG_NEW` overrides the `new` operator for MFC debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz7sxz99.aspx so I'm not sure if your solution would work as well.

Comment: I know that it does that - however you can't be sure that Crypto++ handles MFC's `DEBUG_NEW` correctly. I'm not sure why you think your solution is better. If anything, it disables all the useful memory leak checks that MFC has by commenting this out.