# Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'buffer' when compiling algparam.h

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, crypto++, database-connection

I'm having the same error as [Crypto++ giving a compiler error in algparam.h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15203562/608639) when compiling a game using Crypto++. The error is:

```
Error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'buffer' (at line 397)
```

Here is the code. It starts on line 390 an ends at line 411.

```
#if defined(DEBUG_NEW) && (_MSC_VER >= 1300)
# pragma push_macro("new")
# undef new
#endif

    void MoveInto(void *buffer) const
    {
        AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>* p = new(buffer) AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>(*this);
        CRYPTOPP_UNUSED(p); // silence warning
    }

#if defined(DEBUG_NEW) && (_MSC_VER >= 1300)
# pragma pop_macro("new")
#endif

protected:
    T m_value;
};

CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS AlgorithmParametersTemplate<bool>;
CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS AlgorithmParametersTemplate<int>;
CRYPTOPP_DLL_TEMPLATE_CLASS AlgorithmParametersTemplate<ConstByteArrayParameter>;
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

---

Here are the libraries I use:

- boost 1.67 (tried 1.63 too)
- sqlapi++
- camp
- mysqlcppconns

Here is the error message:

```
1>c:\local\cryptopp\algparam.h(397): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'buffer'
1>c:\local\cryptopp\algparam.h(396): note: while compiling class template member function 'void CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<CryptoPP::ConstByteArrayParameter>::MoveInto(void *) const'
1>c:\local\cryptopp\algparam.h(411): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'CryptoPP::AlgorithmParametersTemplate<CryptoPP::ConstByteArrayParameter>' being compiled
```

Comment: What version of the library are you using? How are you building the library? How are you compiling and linking your program?

Comment: i'm using `cryptopp 7.0 - Debug Mode` for the game. In compilation, I'm using all these libs: `boost 1.67 (tried 1.63 too), sqlapi++, camp, mysqlcppconns`. 
I'm having lots of warnings since the source files are not mine, but all these warnings is ok. this is the link of the github if needed: [Click Here](https://github.com/w0dm4n/Thanadolos)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the problem is. You should probably start by showing the complete error, and not just *"Error  C2061: syntax error : identifier 'buffer' (at line 397)"*. I guess you need to reduce it to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If I had to hazard a guess, it is an unexpected compiler switch or an unusual interaction with one of the other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you are having trouble with from [`algparam.h`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/algparam.h):

```
395    void MoveInto(void *buffer) const
396    {
397        AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>* p = new(buffer) AlgorithmParametersTemplate<T>(*this);
398        CRYPTOPP_UNUSED(p);  // silence warning
399    }
```

I suspect one of the other libraries you are using is messing with the definition on `new`.

I believe you need to compile the source file but instead of producing an object file, you need to use either [/P (Preprocess to a File)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) or [/E (Preprocess to stdout)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xkfswhy.aspx). Once the file is processed take a look at the definition of `new`. From there work back to the library that is changing it.

In the comments you said you also use:

- boost 1.67 (tried 1.63 too)
- sqlapi++
- camp
- mysqlcppconns

Boost does some unusual things at times, and I would suspect boost as the problem.